# Exporting Keras Model Without Dropout Seemingly Fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model with a Tensorflow backend (convolutional neural network) called `model`.  I'm trying to save it without dropout, so it can be used at inference time.

I'm doing this:

```
tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)
yaml_string = model.to_yaml()
```

When I inspect `yaml_string`, I see this included in the string:

```
  - class_name: SpatialDropout1D
    config: {dtype: float32, name: spatial_dropout1d, noise_shape: null, rate: 0.25,
      seed: null, trainable: true}
    inbound_nodes:
    - - - my_embedding_0
        - 0
        - 0
        - {}
    name: spatial_dropout1d
```

This makes me think the `spatial_dropout1d` layer is still there.  Is that a correct interpretation?

If so, how should I be exporting this model without dropout?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is still there, setting the learning phase does nothing at all in this case. I am not sure why you think you need to do anything special for Dropout to work at inference time, its all done automatically.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Got it, thanks!